# Mapping 1 to 0-1 In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Doing Entity Framework (5) code first, although we are not generating our data model from the code--we just keep them in sync manually (less of a pain than it sounds).

Trying to create a 1 to 0-1 relationship.  Here is the setup using a made-up example of a customer that could have 0 or 1 address:

**Edit: original example was not right.  Customer can have 0-1 Addresses, Address has exactly 1 customer.  Table design and code both updated.**

```
Address
--------------
AddressId (identity)
AddressText
CustomerId (Edit: this employs a unique constraint)
```

```
Customer
--------------
CustomerId (identity)
CustomerName
```

Relevant part of Address mapping:

```
   this.HasKey(t => t.AddressId);
   //SEE NOTE ON THIS BELOW
   //this.Property(t =>t.AddressId).
                   HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
   this.HasRequired(t => t.Customer)
       .WithOptional();
```

Relevant part of Customer mapping:

```
  this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerId);
   this.HasOptional(b => b.Address)
            .WithRequired();
```

Note the line commented out in Customer.  If I include this, I get the following error:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column: 'CustomerId'.

If I don't include it, I get:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customer'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I have searched high and low, and the code above seems to be the recommended approach.  I have also seen some vague mention that 1:1 relationships can't be modeled unless the two tables share a key of the same name?

Can this sort of relationship be modeled in code, and if so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping looks invalid. You are saying that an `Address` has an optional `Customer`, and a `Customer` has a required address, but your `Address` foriegn key on your `Customer` entity is nullable, so the relationship should be the other way around.

Also, yes, if you want to model a 1 to 1 relationship, then you should have a `Customer` table with a primary key, and then an `Address` table with a primary key column which is also a foreign key to your `Customer` table.

Otherwise, you are really modelling a one-to-many relationship in the database.

Comment: Sorry, the example was flawed.  Can you take another look?

Comment: Ok, you are still modelling a one-to-many relationship in the database. Remove the CustomerId foriegn key from the Address table, and make the primary key (AddressId) the foriegn key. The reason is to ensure that no more than one entity exists in the dependent end (Address) for each entity in the principal end (Customer), as the primary key constraint enforces uniqueness.

Comment: The CustomerId on Address has a unique constraint, which effectively makes it a 1:1 (and SQL Server recognizes it as such).  I should have mentioned that in my initial post (edited to add it).

Comment: Ah ok, is this CustomerId column marked as an identify column by any chance?

Comment: In the database, both PKs are set up as identity.  Both seem to meet the convention for EF assuming they are identity in the code as well.  As noted by the commented out code, I get a different result if I explicitly call out the AddressId as an identity.

Comment: Not the primary keys, the CustomerId foreign key, is this marked as an identity column accidently?

Comment: No, only the PKs of each table are using HasKey (which seems to be what controls the identity convention).

Comment: I'm confused, you said you weren't generating your data model from the code?

Comment: We're not generating--the EF uses a convention to "assume" whether a PK is an identity or not.  I think if it's a PK and ends in "Id", it assumes it is an identity unless you tell it otherwise.  That's based on experience--I've never seen this explicitly in any documentation.

Comment: EF will by default mark int keys as database generated values. There is something wrong with your data model, I would recommend getting EF to generate the data model from your code on a clean database, and then doing a schema compare.

Comment: My guess would be that the foreign key in Address has to also be the primary key as originally stated, which would be the preferred way to model the data anyway, as it elimates redundant data in the Address table.

Comment: Ok, may have to do it that way.  It's not my preferred way of modelling the database, and seems like EF has the *capability* to make it work (whether it's actually implemented to be possible or not).  Thanks for your help.